# cordova in visual studio 2015 update2 deploy failed

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

After the update 2, the released apk could be built but cannot be installed. And each kind of emulator performs as follows:

VS Emulator 5" KitKat:

```
1>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
1>
1>  Total time: 3.793 secs
1>  Built the following apk(s):
1>      E:/sdudio/Carpass/Carpass/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk
1>  Executing "after_compile"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "after_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ------ 正在复制回项目: Android
1>  ------ 已将 platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unaligned.apk 复制到 E:\sdudio\Carpass\Carpass\bin\Android\Release\android-release-unaligned.apk
1>  ------ 已将 platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release.apk 复制到 E:\sdudio\Carpass\Carpass\bin\Android\Release\android-release.apk
1>  ------ 已复制编译的文件: Android
2>------ begain deploy: Project: Carpass, 配置: Release Android ------
2>  Validating emulator arguments...
2>  Determining if emulator is already running...
2>  Emulator is already running.
```

The emulator runs normally but nothing is installed and it keeps deploying as long as I stop building.

Google Android Emulator:
The project runs well on the Emulator, while vs says it build successfully but failed in deploying. And it doesn't show any mistakes, only a warning:No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_21.

Ripple:
Runs normally.

Device:

```
2>------ 已启动部署: 项目: Carpass, 配置: Release Android ------
2>  正在向 ADB 查询连接的设备...
2>系统找不到指定的文件。
2>系统找不到指定的文件。
```

It builds successfully and begin deploying, asking the ADB if there is a device connected. And then it shows the mistake:"The system cannot find the specified file." The source of the mistake is Intellisense.
The released apk cannot be installed on device.

I've tried unistall vs2015, modify vs 2015, repair vs 2015, and  [Tools] > [Options] > Text Editor > JavaScript > IntelliSense > References options add a Intellisense.js for cordova but it does nothing.
Newly build a project or clear the cordova cache, no use...

Comment: Try run your vs 2015 as administrator. And see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I tried run as administrator and there's no difference...

Comment: Do you have a device to test? Check https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-apache/#android-devices doc and follow the instructions under Android Devices section to ensure the device is correctly attached. And then try to run adb command to deploy the app out of Visual Studio. Refer to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html. Let me know if there is any error.

Comment: Since you can launch the emulator correctly, then adb devices command also works for the emulator after you launched it. For example:C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
.And we expect this result: List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device . After that, use adb command to deploy your apk to this device.

Comment: How about using other emulators? like ripple or VS emulators for Android?

Comment: I have also used android studio on this computer, and the device runs ok. Ripple can open my app successfully, VS emulator opened but installed nothing.I think there are some mistakes with the intellisense. A few days ago I found there are two SDK manager, one is for android studio so the other I think is for VS. Although my VS says all SDKs were installed,  the SDK manager says not, so I moved some files and all the two were damaged, this time the VS shows no mistakes but the generated apk still couldn't be installed. Maybe I need to reinstall the whole system.Thank you any way

Comment: On another cumputer which has never installed VS, I succeeded to install a app on real mobile phone last weekend. It was said that VS cannot be uninstall completely....